# How to us CIL opcode bne.un vs beq, and bne.un.s vs beq.s, unsigned vs signed equality

Tags: c#, f#, jit, cil

I understand that `beq` is applicable to more scenarios than `bne.un` (and it's equality vs inequality), but I'm wondering if there's any difference. For instance, suppose I use a `char` and have `x == y`, I would expect `beq.un`, but that doesn't exist, so I get `bne.un`, but when i use `x != y`, I get `beq`. How is it that an unsigned comparison can lead to a signed comparison instruction? Does it even matter? (hint: probably not, because that is what the compilers do, but why then the difference?).

Example:

```
  .method public static char  test(char x) cil managed
  {
    // Code size       11 (0xb)
    .maxstack  8
    IL_0000:  ldc.i4.s   97
    IL_0002:  ldarg.0
    IL_0003:  beq.un.s   IL_0008

    IL_0005:  ldc.i4.s   65
    IL_0007:  ret

    IL_0008:  ldc.i4.s   66
    IL_000a:  ret
  }
```

vs:

```
  .method public static char  test(char x) cil managed
  {
    // Code size       11 (0xb)
    .maxstack  8
    IL_0000:  ldc.i4.s   97
    IL_0002:  ldarg.0
    IL_0003:  beq.s      IL_0008

    IL_0005:  ldc.i4.s   65
    IL_0007:  ret

    IL_0008:  ldc.i4.s   66
    IL_000a:  ret
  }
```

Example C# code:

```cs
// this compiles to `bne.un.s`
public class C {
    public bool M(char x) {
        if(x == 'A')
            return true;
        return false;
    }
}

// this compiles to `beq.s`
public class C {
    public bool M(char x) {
        if(x != 'A')
            return true;
        return false;
    }
}
```

See the sharplab code:

- [first example](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LglgNgPgAgzAAhgJgQYQQbwLACgEFKIBGA9qRAgLIAUAxgBYCGATggB4CUWehfCYAGY12CALxiEAcgCCUzr35KYAdgTAWAVwCmAbkXK1gphADOegwgC+eK0A==).
- [second example](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LglgNgPgAgzAAhgJgQYQQbwLACgEFKIBGA9qRAgLIAUAxgBYCGATggB4CUWehfCYAGY12CAIQBeBAHIAgtM69+ymAHYEwFgFcApgG4lK9YKYQAzvsMIAvnmtA=).

I'm surprised at the difference here between how `==` gets translated to the (seemingly more correct) `bne.un.s`, and that `!=` gets translated to the more general `beq.s` without using any unsigned instruction.

The compiled JITted machine code doesn't show that this leads to different assembly (which is good):

```
    L0000: movzx eax, dx
    L0003: cmp eax, 0x41
    L0006: jne short L000e   ; will be je for `!=`
    L0008: mov eax, 1
    L000d: ret
    L000e: xor eax, eax
    L0010: ret
```

But is this always the case? The documentation on these opcodes doesn't suggest it is wrong to use either opcode as long as the outcome is correct.

Background: I came across this idiosyncrasy while working on [this PR for F# on the `not` function](https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/pull/9715) and got curious.

Comment: Your question seems a bit confused: there's no instruction `beq.un`, and the examples talk about `beq.s` and `bne.un.s` (but not `beq.un`)?

Comment: @canton7, thanks for spotting that! I'll update. EDIT: done.

Comment: And it seems that `beq` and `bne.un` are just opposites: there's no `beq.un` or `bne`. If you read the docs they're both exactly equivalent to running `ceq`, but one branches on true and the other on false. I'm not sure what `bne.un` has to do with unsigned values particularly, the compiler uses it for signed ints as well. I suspect it's because it compares *unordered* floats ("**b**ranch if **n**ot **e**qual or **un**ordered")

Comment: @canton7, that seems a good explanation for my misunderstanding. You may certainly put that in an answer. It also makes sense that there's an unordered in inequality and never in equality, which wouldn't make sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "unsigned" bit is odd. The docs for `beq` don't mention signed/unsigned values or floats, but the docs for `bne.un` explicitly say that it applies to unsigned values and floats. However, the compiler uses `bne.un` for signed values as well as unsigned values.

Regardless, the [docs for `beq`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.beq) do say:

> The effect is the same as performing a `ceq` instruction followed by a `brtrue` branch to the specific target instruction

while the [docs for `bne.un`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.bne_un) say:

> The effect is identical to performing a `ceq` instruction followed by a `brfalse` branch to the specific target instruction

so I think it's safe to assume that they're exact opposites of each other, and can be used in any place that `ceq` can be used.

The docs for `ceq` mention floats, but not signed / unsigned ints.

---

My suspicion is that `beq.un` is so named because it branches if the values it's given are equal, or are unordered floats ("**b**ranch if **eq**ual or **un**ordered floats). It's possible that an over-zealous documentation writer misinterpreted "un" to mean "unsigned" (as it does for the rest of the `bxx.un` instructions), and this propagated.

Signedness matters when comparing ints (i.e. asking whether one is greater than or less than another), but not for testing whether they're equal: if both operands have the same signedness, you just need to check whether their bit patterns are identical. This is why you have e.g. both `ble` and `ble.un`, but there's no `beq.un`.

Comment: Thanks! I had a look at "CLI Annotated Standard" page 526 and on. It appears that "unordered" is not related to the _type of the arg_, but the _value_ being `NaN` or not. As such, it is the exact counterpart of `beq`, which treats `nan == nan` as unequal, and `bne.un` has `nan != nan` as true. I agree that the note "when compared unsigned" is redundant here. I figured it meant the args must be of unsigned type, but that's not true, it is about semantics. For _unordered values_ the notes on comparison ops specifically mention `nan`, just not for the branch instrs.

Comment: Yeah, the MSDN docs for `bne.un` say much the same thing: *"The bne.un instruction transfers control to the specified target instruction if value1 is not equal to value2, when compared using unsigned integer or **unordered float values**"*. I just think it's wrong on the "unsigned integer" bit